# UIButton images for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, ios-autolayout, size-classes

I need bigger button & image sizes for iPad devices compared to iPhone. Before Size classes, I used to have images ending as @2x~ipad to have different version for iPad. However, it is not clear if the same approach is applicable when using Size classes and Trait collections, or there is a better approach? Also, is iPad Pro 12.9 inch @3x or @2x? I see conflicting responses, but if it is @2x, how do we have bigger image size for iPad Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Size with Resolution.

If you have a **UIImageView** at `150 x 150` ***points***, and you have `MyPic.png` + `MyPic@2x.png` + `MyPic@3x.png`, the image view's ***frame*** will always be `150 x 150` ***points***, but `UIKit` will automatically select the proper *resolution* image for the device. See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

If you want different size ***frames*** for your buttons and images, based on device / view size, use Trait Variations, or code, or percentage-based constraints.

Again, if you have `MyPic.png` + `MyPic@2x.png` + `MyPic@3x.png` files of the same image, the appropriate resolution image will be used, regardless of ***frame*** size.

There is a lot of flexibility when working with images by using Asset Catalogs. For example:

[image]

You can add different resolution images for 1x 2x and 3x... you can add image sets specific to iPhone / iPad / etc.

---

**EDIT**

Additional example. Asset is named "RoundSwift256x256". I have 3 resolutions for iPhone, 2 resolutions for iPad (no iPads use @3x) - using different colors to make it very obvious.

[image]

In Storyboard, I added an imageView, set its image to `RoundSwift256x256`. then set the Assistant Editor to Preview and selected iPhone 8 and iPad Pro 9.7". As you see, it uses my iPhone image for iPhone, and my iPad image for iPad.

[image]

Comment: I changed frame sizes for iPad using trait variations. For the images, is using @2x~ipad still correct and no obsolete?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using Asset Catalogs... you can easily organize your images, define image sets for different devices, etc.

Comment: I only see way to add 1x, 2x, 3x images in Asset Catelog, not iPad.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - see the edit to my answer, and do a search for `xcode asset catalog help` to learn how to use the Asset Catalog

Comment: And how to use these images in Storyboard?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you read through the documentation and a few articles on using Asset Catalogs?

Comment: Ok found it, thank you. Easy to access in code as well as Storyboard!

Comment: Basically even in asset catalog, for each button I am creating an image set for both normal & selected state. There will be over 100 image sets this way -- both for normal & selected state of UIButton. I am wondering if there is an easier way and if asset catalog really makes things simple and automated?

Comment: You *can* still use the `~iphone` / `~ipad` file naming approach. Or, you can use a script to automate the creation of your image sets in the asset catalog. My original comment stands though -- you were confusing Size with Resolution. Hopefully that is clear now.